# Biblatex: Automatic *Vgl.* & automatic quote indenting (depending on quote length)

Tags: biblatex, citing, quoting

Is it possible to create a command that:

1. Whenever it exceeds a certain number of lines in the output (preferably 3), it will be typeset indented.
2. The citation will automatically be typeset without "*Vgl.*" -- regardless of whether it is the short or the long form.
3. When the output is a paraphrase or summary (in other words: when the output is no citation) it is typeset with the prenote "*Vgl*".
4. It works in `biblatex`.

Related answers for inspiration:

In [Linking quotation environment with citation styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57408/linking-quotation-environment-with-citation-styles) lockstep worked out a quotation command based on `biblatex` that automatically generates a "*Vgl.*"-less output when used in a citation environment. And that generates a "*Vgl.*" output when used without quotation mark.

Output-Example:

> This is a paraphrase (vgl. Author 2001)
>
> This is a paraphrase with prenote (siehe hierzu auch Author 2001)
>
> "This is a direct quotation" (Author 2001)

The Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetCiteCommand{\autocite}

% \usepackage{etoolbox}% loaded by `biblatex` 

\newbool{withintextquote}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\csq@tquote@i}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\booltrue{withintextquote}}{}{}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{A01}

\textcquote{A01}{This is a direct quotation}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

In [Custom quotation style which depends on length of quotation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19008/custom-quotation-style-which-depends-on-length-of-quotation) Martin Scharrer worked out a way to generate quotations that are typeset indented or unindented -- depending on the length of the quotation. The main point with this command is: Whenever the quotation exceeds a certain number of lines in the typeset output, it will be indented.

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter \newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi } \makeatother

\begin{document}

% Lipsum add paragraphs :-( \def\Text{text text text text text } \edef\Text{\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text}

\Text \cquotation{some short quote} \Text

\Text \cquotation{% Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines. } \Text

\Text \cquotation{% Some quotation shorter than three lines.

But with a paragraph inside. } \Text

\Text \cquotation{% Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. } \Text

\end{document}


% Lipsum add paragraphs :-( \def\Text{text text text text text } \edef\Text{\Text\Text\Text\Text\Text}

\Text \cquotation{some short quote} \Text

\Text \cquotation{% Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines of text. Some quotation just short of three lines. } \Text

\Text \cquotation{% Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. Some quotation longer than three lines.  Some quotation longer than three lines. } \Text

\end{document}
```

**Note**. There occur two minor problems with this command.

1. Whenever you use `\autocites{}{}` with more than one source you will get something like *vgl. Grice (1989); vgl. Levinson (2000).* including more than one *vgl.*.
2. When you use this command with `autocite=footnote` the counter will "jump" two steps with every `\autocite` that is embedded in a `\cquotation{}`, e.g. whenever you have something like this `\cquotation{text text text \autocite{}.}` the counter will add two instead of one. Thus, the numbering of your footnotes will look odd (for example 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9 ...).

Both issues are successfully addressed in moewe's answer to [Biblatex: Problems with *vgl.* and numbering in dynamic quotation command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149373/biblatex-problems-with-vgl-and-numbering-in-dynamic-quotation-command).

Comment: It seems you essentially put a copy of my answer into the original question, which now isn't really a "question" anymore. As TeX.sx is a Q+A site, please consider to rewrite your post into a proper question or at least to revert to the former version.

Comment: I've rolled back the edits to more-or-less the 'original' state. There's no problem with editing the question after it's been answered, but it really should stay in the form of a question about more-or-less the same topic.

Comment: @lockstep and Joseph Wright: Ok, thank you both for your comments. Maybe I will try a more adequate re-write another day again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you want to use the citation commands of `biblatex` in the argument of Martin Scharrer's `\cquotation` command, the latter needs to be patched so that it sets the `withintextquote` boolean of my linked answer to true inside a group.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\newbool{withintextquote}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}

\cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{A01}}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Again, thank you. But there is one minor issue: Is it possible to have the brackets and the author in a non-italic font as in the paraphrases?

Comment: @Philip Add `\appto{\citesetup}{\upshape}` to your preamble.

Comment: I am using your device in every document and I it saves me a lot of work. But now a little imperfection surfaced: `\citeauthor{asdf}` (where "asdf" is defined as "author = {Smith}") is typeset as "vgl. Smith" and not as "Smith" as it should be. Is it possible to get rid of this one?

Comment: @Philip: As a workaround try `\citeauthor[\unspace][]{asdf}`.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround. There is a little problem. If you use the workaround in a "normal" way (meaning for me: using space before and after the command as if it were a word) you get a double space between the previous text and the cited author what looks odd in the output. To get the right spacing in the output you can use the workarout without a space what looks odd in the code. "The problem is also adressed by\citeauthor[\unspace][]{asdf}." I am wondering if there is a solution that satisfies readability in both the output and the underlying code.

Comment: @Philip: An inelegant solution. To avoid the odd spacing in either the output or the code, the code can be extended. It reads like this `\citeauthor[\hspace{-4px}\unspace][]{pW93}`.

Comment: Another minor imperfection surfaced: When this device is used with `\autociteS` it tends to produce footnotes like this "24 vgl. Grice (1989); vgl. Levinson (2000); vgl. Singer (1993).". Is it possible to include the vgl. only one time in the beginning of the citation and leave it out in the following instead of including it in front of every cited work. Thus, producing "24 vgl. Grice (1989); Levinson (2000); Singer (1993)".