# Biblatex: Problems with *vgl.* and numbering in dynamic quotation command

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

In [Biblatex: Automatic *Vgl.* & automatic quote indenting (depending on quote length)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57908/biblatex-automatic-vgl-automatic-quote-indenting-depending-on-quote-lengt) lockstep creates a quotation command based on previous contribitions by lockstep and Martin Scharrer that

1. Whenever it exceeds a certain number of lines in the output (preferably 3), it will be typeset indented.
2. The citation will automatically be typeset without "Vgl." -- regardless of whether it is the short or the long form.
3. When the output is a paraphrase or summary (in other words: when the output is no citation) it is typeset with the prenote "Vgl".
4. It works in biblatex.

The main purpose is to automize both the *vgl.* (engl. compare) and the line indention.

After using this command for quite a while two minor problems occured.

1. Whenever you use `\autocites{}{}` with more than one source you will get something like *vgl. Grice (1989); vgl. Levinson (2000).* including more than one *vgl.*. The question: Is it possible to have a *vgl.* just one time in the beginning and suppress it for all following sources of the same `\autocite{}{}`, thus generating *vgl. Grice (1989); Levinson (2000).* without any additional *vgl.*.
2. When you use this command with *autocite=footnote* the counter will "jump" two steps with every `\autocite` that is embedded in a `\cquotation{}`, e.g. whenever you have something like this `\cquotation{text text text \autocite{}.}` the counter will add two instead of one.

Does anyone know how to solve these problems?

Below you find locksteps code. To produce my particular problem I added `autocite=footnote` and Ì added `This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}{A01}` twice in the beginning.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex} % Here, Philip added "autocite=footnote"

\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\newbool{withintextquote}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}

\cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{A01}}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like the following modifications

Problem 1 is addressed by redefining the `multicite` `multiprenote` bibmacro.
If we are in a `prenote` situation, we redefine the `multiprenote` to add the "vgl" note and redefine the normal `prenote` not to do so.

Problem 2 can be dealt with by disabling the footnote command within the box used to evaluate the length of the text.
The command `cquotation` typesets the text in its argument twice: once invisible to check its length (to decide what to do with the text) and once properly; the invisible typesetting increases the footnote numbering as well, so you get double-steps.

```
\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\printfield{prenote}%
       \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
  \iffieldundef{multiprenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{multiprenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
        \let\autocite\@empty
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Our MWE then yields

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex} % Here, Philip added "autocite=footnote"

\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\newbool{withintextquote}

\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\printfield{prenote}%
       \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
  \iffieldundef{multiprenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{multiprenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
        \let\autocite\@empty
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}

\cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{A01}}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{A01}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you use `csquotes` you might like to have a look at `blockquote`, a very sophisticated implementation of the inline/paragraph switching.

We can also borrow an internal macro for our purposes: `\blockquote@parsehook` disables all unwanted fragile parts of LaTeX code such as footnotes, marginnotes, labels and index commands in the `savebox`. There even is a command for users to add commands to be disabled within `blockquote` evaluations: `\BlockquoteDisable{}`.

The `\cquotation` command then becomes.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        %\let\blx@thecheckpunct\@gobble
        \blockquote@parsehook
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

Comment: A new problem occured. If you use the `\cquotation` and it doesnt exceed 3 lines, now it will generate a line break which is not desired. So if you type in *bla bla bla \cquotation{asdf asdf asdf asdf} hjkl hjkl hjkl* you will find an odd line break following the last *bla*. Is it possible to fix this issue.

Comment: @Philip That behaviour is easily fixed, I seem to have accidentally added a blank line to lockstep's code which causes the line break. It should be fixed now, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Without the *vgl.* the `\blockquote` command doesnt meet one crucial requirement. My thesis has about 200 pages and to change the *vgl.* manually would be too much of a hassle. Maybe, I will post a question at some point if anyone can combine the `\blockquote` with *vgl.*. For now I am happy that it works. So, again, thank you!