# Biblatex: Combining Dynamic Compare Command with a '\citetitle' Command

Tags: biblatex, citing, quoting

In [How to create a \citejournal, \citebooktitle, \cite… command in biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26682/how-to-create-a-citejournal-citebooktitle-cite-command-in-biblatex) Gonzalo Medina and Audrey provided code that works like `\citeauthor{}`e.g. when you put in your document it creates just the title of a book or a journal ... This problem occurs for the `\citeauthor`command as well.

In [Automatic *Vgl.* & automatic quote indenting (depending on quote length)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57908/biblatex-automatic-vgl-automatic-quote-indenting-depending-on-quote-lengt) lockstep creates a quotation command based on previous contribitions by lockstep and Martin Scharrer that

1. Whenever it exceeds a certain number of lines in the output (preferably 3), it will be typeset indented.
2. The citation will automatically be typeset without "Vgl." -- regardless of whether it is the short or the long form.
3. When the output is a paraphrase or summary (in other words: when the output is no citation) it is typeset with the prenote "Vgl".
4. It works in biblatex.

The main purpose is to automize both the *vgl.* (engl. compare) and the line indention.

**The problem:** Unfortunately, when you combine both codes the prenote *vgl.* will precede each `\citeauthor`, `\citetitle` etc. command in the output. You will get *vgl. Author* instead of *Author*. Is there anyone who could fix this problem globally?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % Here, Philip added "autocite=footnote,backend=bibtex"

%-------------------
\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\newbool{withintextquote}

\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\printfield{prenote}%
       \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
  \iffieldundef{multiprenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{multiprenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
        \let\autocite\@empty
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother

%-------------------

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{journal}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citebooktitle}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeintitle}% Based on \citetitle from biblatex.def
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
     {\iffieldundef{booktitle}
        {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
          {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}% Behave like \citetitle if no "main" title
          {\printtext[maintitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{maintitle}}}}
        {\printtext[booktitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}}}}
     {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

  \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{yoon,
  author = {Yoon, Myeong S. and Ryu, Dowook and Kim, Jeongryul and Ahn, Kyo Han},
  title = {Palladium pincer complexes with reduced bond angle strain: efficient catalysts
    for the Heck reaction},
  journaltitle = {Organometallics},
  volume = {25},
  number = {10},
  date = {2006},
  pages = {2409--2411}}
@InProceedings{salam,
  author = {Salam, Abdus},
  editor = {Svartholm, Nils},
  title = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
  booktitle = {Elementary Particle Theory},
  booksubtitle = {Relativistic Groups and Analyticity},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the Eighth Nobel Symposium},
  eventdate = {1968-05-19/1968-05-25},
  venue = {Aspen{\"a}sgarden, Lerum},
  publisher = {Almquist \& Wiksell},
  location = {Stockholm},
  date = {1968},
  pages = {367--377}}
@InProceedings{moraux,
  author = {Moraux, Paul},
  editor = {Lloyd, G. E. R. and Owen, G. E. L.},
  title = {Le \emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  subtitle = {Quelques aspects de l'interpretation du trait{\'e}, de Theophraste {\`a}
    Themistius},
  shorttitle = {\emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  booktitle = {Aristotle on Mind and the Senses},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the Seventh Symposium Aristotelicum},
  eventdate = {1975},
  publisher = cup,
  location = {Cambridge},
  date = {1979},
  pages = {281--324}}
@InCollection{pines,
  author = {Pines, Shlomo},
  editor = {Twersky, Isadore},
  indextitle = {Limitations of Human Knowledge According to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and
    Maimonides, The},
  title = {The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and
    Maimonides},
  shorttitle = {Limitations of Human Knowledge},
  booktitle = {Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature},
  publisher = hup,
  location = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  date = {1979},
  pages = {82--109}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{yoon}}

\cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{yoon}}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{yoon}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{yoon}}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}

\noindent
\citeintitle{yoon} versus \citejournal{yoon} \\\\
\citeintitle{salam} versus \citebooktitle{salam} \\\\
\citeintitle{moraux} versus \citebooktitle{moraux} \\\\
\citeintitle{pines} versus \citebooktitle{pines}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note1: The *vgl.* code used here is slightly refined by moewe based on the version of lockstep. It avoids strange numbering and a undesired output of the prenote *vgl.* in `autocite=footnote` setting in biblatex (the link [Biblatex: Problems with *vgl.* and numbering in dynamic quotation command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149373/biblatex-problems-with-vgl-and-numbering-in-dynamic-quotation-command)).

Note2: For the `\citeauthor{}` the problem could be fixed by replacing the command by `\citeauthor[\unspace][]{}`. As this affects the readability, a global solution would be prefered. However, maybe a global solution may build on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a new `\newbibmacro*{simp:prenote}` that never prints any "vgl"/compare stuff

```
\newbibmacro*{simp:prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}
```

(This, incidentally, is the standard definition of `bibmacro{prenote}` in `biblatex.def`.)

We then use this simple bib macro in all the `\citetitle`/`\citeauthor` and friends macros

We have to redefine the standard `\citeauthor`/`\citetitle` macros to use `simp:prenote`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[][1-1]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citedate}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printdate}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citedate}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printdateextra}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurl}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printfield[citeurl]{url}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\notecite}
  {\printfield{simp:prenote}%
   \setunit*{\prenotedelim}}
  {\nocite{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {}
  {\printfield{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
  {\usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{journal}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citebooktitle}
  {\usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeintitle}% Based on \citetitle from biblatex.def
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
     {\iffieldundef{booktitle}
        {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
          {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}% Behave like \citetitle if no "main" title
          {\printtext[maintitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{maintitle}}}}
        {\printtext[booktitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}}}}
     {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

That is quite a lot of code, but quite straightforward.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote,backend=bibtex]{biblatex} % Here, Philip added "autocite=footnote,backend=bibtex"

%-------------------
\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\newbool{withintextquote}

\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\printfield{prenote}%
       \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
  \iffieldundef{multiprenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{multiprenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\newbibmacro*{simp:prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}
    {}
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
        \let\autocite\@empty
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother

%-------------------

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printnames[][1-1]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citetitle}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \printfield[citetitle]{title}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeyear}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printfield{year}\printfield{extrayear}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citedate}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printdate}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citedate}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printdateextra}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurl}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\printfield[citeurl]{url}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\notecite}
  {\printfield{simp:prenote}%
   \setunit*{\prenotedelim}}
  {\nocite{\thefield{entrykey}}}
  {}
  {\printfield{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citejournal}
  {\usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{journal}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citebooktitle}
  {\usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{booktitle}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeintitle}% Based on \citetitle from biblatex.def
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{simp:prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexfield{indextitle}}
     {}%
   \iffieldundef{journaltitle}
     {\iffieldundef{booktitle}
        {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
          {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}% Behave like \citetitle if no "main" title
          {\printtext[maintitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{maintitle}}}}
        {\printtext[booktitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{booktitle}}}}
     {\printtext[journaltitle]{\printfield[titlecase]{journaltitle}}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

  \usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{yoon,
  author = {Yoon, Myeong S. and Ryu, Dowook and Kim, Jeongryul and Ahn, Kyo Han},
  title = {Palladium pincer complexes with reduced bond angle strain: efficient catalysts
    for the Heck reaction},
  journaltitle = {Organometallics},
  volume = {25},
  number = {10},
  date = {2006},
  pages = {2409--2411}}
@InProceedings{salam,
  author = {Salam, Abdus},
  editor = {Svartholm, Nils},
  title = {Weak and Electromagnetic Interactions},
  booktitle = {Elementary Particle Theory},
  booksubtitle = {Relativistic Groups and Analyticity},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the Eighth Nobel Symposium},
  eventdate = {1968-05-19/1968-05-25},
  venue = {Aspen{\"a}sgarden, Lerum},
  publisher = {Almquist \& Wiksell},
  location = {Stockholm},
  date = {1968},
  pages = {367--377}}
@InProceedings{moraux,
  author = {Moraux, Paul},
  editor = {Lloyd, G. E. R. and Owen, G. E. L.},
  title = {Le \emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  subtitle = {Quelques aspects de l'interpretation du trait{\'e}, de Theophraste {\`a}
    Themistius},
  shorttitle = {\emph{De Anima} dans la tradition gr{\`e}cque},
  booktitle = {Aristotle on Mind and the Senses},
  booktitleaddon = {Proceedings of the Seventh Symposium Aristotelicum},
  eventdate = {1975},
  publisher = cup,
  location = {Cambridge},
  date = {1979},
  pages = {281--324}}
@InCollection{pines,
  author = {Pines, Shlomo},
  editor = {Twersky, Isadore},
  indextitle = {Limitations of Human Knowledge According to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and
    Maimonides, The},
  title = {The Limitations of Human Knowledge According to Al-Farabi, ibn Bajja, and
    Maimonides},
  shorttitle = {Limitations of Human Knowledge},
  booktitle = {Studies in Medieval Jewish History and Literature},
  publisher = hup,
  location = {Cambridge, Mass.},
  date = {1979},
  pages = {82--109}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{yoon}}

\cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{yoon}}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{yoon}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{yoon}{yoon} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{yoon}}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{yoon}

\noindent
\citeauthor{yoon} versus \citetitle{yoon} \\\\
\citeintitle{yoon} versus \citejournal{yoon} \\\\
\citeintitle{salam} versus \citebooktitle{salam} \\\\
\citeintitle{moraux} versus \citebooktitle{moraux} \\\\
\citeintitle{pines} versus \citebooktitle{pines}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```