# Biblatex: Improving Dynamic Quotation Command

Tags: biblatex, citing, quoting

In [Biblatex: Automatic *Vgl.* & automatic quote indenting (depending on quote length)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57908/biblatex-automatic-vgl-automatic-quote-indenting-depending-on-quote-lengt) lockstep creates a quotation command based on previous contribitions by lockstep and Martin Scharrer that

1. Whenever it exceeds a certain number of lines in the output (preferably 3), it will be typeset indented.
2. The citation will automatically be typeset without "Vgl." -- regardless of whether it is the short or the long form.
3. When the output is a paraphrase or summary (in other words: when the output is no citation) it is typeset with the prenote "Vgl".
4. It works in biblatex.

The main purpose is to automize both the *vgl.* (engl. compare) and the line indention.

**The question**:

1. Is it possible to change the 3 lines exceeding version to single spacing (while using `\usepackage{setspace}` and `\onehalfspacing`)?
2. Is it possible to produce slightly smaller text than in the "proper" text in the 3 line exceeding version?
3. Used in a `footnote{}`, is it possible to adjust its size to the footnote text when it exceeds 3 lines?
4. And is anyone able to do it?

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex} % Here, Philip added "autocite=footnote"

\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\newbool{withintextquote}

\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\printfield{prenote}%
       \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
  \iffieldundef{multiprenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{multiprenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
        \let\autocite\@empty
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}

\cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{A01}}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{A01}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

\footnote{This is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is   aThis is aThis is a \cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{A01}} This is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis   is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is a }

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note: The *vgl.* code used here is slightly refined by moewe based on the version of lockstep. It avoids strange numbering and a undesired output of the prenote *vgl.* in `autocite=footnote` setting in biblatex (the link [Biblatex: Problems with *vgl.* and numbering in dynamic quotation command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149373/biblatex-problems-with-vgl-and-numbering-in-dynamic-quotation-command)). In addition, you find a `\newbibmacro*{simp:prenote}{...` by moewe to avoid confusion with another command (see [Biblatex: Combining Dynamic Compare Command with a '\citetitle' Command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164108/biblatex-combining-dynamic-compare-command-with-a-citetitle-command)). And, I added the `\usepackage{setspace}` and `\onehalfspacing`.

Comment: 1. and 2. are quite easily dealt with; for footnote detection there is something more to be done (http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147350/35864).

Comment: @moewe Since biblatex is loaded for this, couldn't one use `\iffootnote` for that?

Comment: @PaulStanley Yep, at first I could not get it to work, but I think it works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following redefinition of `\cquotation` could help.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
        \let\autocite\@empty
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \singlespacing
            \smaller
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\blx@blxinit\iffootnote{\smaller}{}\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The long quote (text exceeding 3 lines) will be printed in `\singlespacing` and smaller (the `\smaller` command is courtesy of Don­ald Arse­neau's [`relsize`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package, so we load `\usepackage{relsize}`).

While the short form will be printed smaller only if it appears in a footnote; to detect the footnote we use `\iffootnote`, a `biblatex` command that is only available after issuing `\blx@blxinit`.

Note that the size calculations are done in double spacing and normal font size.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,autocite=footnote]{biblatex} % Here, Philip added "autocite=footnote"

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{relsize}
\onehalfspacing
\NewBibliographyString{compare}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{%
  compare = {vgl\adddot},
}

\newbool{withintextquote}

\renewbibmacro*{multiprenote}{%
  \renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
    \iffieldundef{prenote}
      {}
      {\printfield{prenote}%
       \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}%
  \iffieldundef{multiprenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{multiprenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\renewbibmacro*{prenote}{%
  \iffieldundef{prenote}{%
    \ifbool{withintextquote}{%
    }{%
      \bibstring{compare}\addspace
    }%
    }
    {\printfield{prenote}%
     \setunit{\prenotedelim}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cquotation}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \booltrue{withintextquote}%
    % \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
        %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
        \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
        \let\autocite\@empty
        #1}%
    \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>3\linewidth
        \begin{quote}
            \singlespacing
            \itshape
            #1
        \end{quote}
    \else
        {\blx@blxinit\iffootnote{\smaller}{}\itshape #1}%
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}

\cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{A01}}

    This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase with prenote \autocite[siehe hierzu auch][]{A01}

This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

This is a paraphrase \autocites{A01}{A01} % Added by Philip

\cquotation{This is a short direct quotation. \autocite{A01}}
This is a paraphrase \autocite{A01}

\footnote{This is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is   aThis is aThis is a \cquotation{This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation. This is a long direct quotation. This is a long direct
    quotation.\autocite{A01}} This is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis   is aThis is aThis is aThis is aThis is a }

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi moewe, thank you. It works perfectly fine. But there is one minor imperfection. The space before and behind the quotation in the 3 line exceeding version is not identical. Is it possible to adjust the preceding space to the following space?

Comment: @Philip The easiest would be to issue a `\vspace{-1.4em}` (or similar, I could not tell the best value, play around with it) before the `\begin{quote}`.