# Italic page numbers using gb4e

Tags: citing, gb4e

A while I asked multiple questions regarding the construction of a quotation environment that - among others - is automatically indenting when exceeding a certain number of lines and that is automatically including information regarding direct and indirect quotations. The result is the `varquote`environment.

I use the code heavily in my linguistic documents. At the same time, I use the `\usepackage{gb4e}`.

The problem is that the output shows an italic page number when the `\varquote{}`environment is at the end or the beginning of a page, or when it is floating from one page to the next. If I delete the `gb4e`environment the problem does not occur.

**My Question**: Is there a way to avoid the problem and use the `varquote`and `gb4e`at the same time?

MWE (if you delete `gb4e`the problem is gone)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} 

\usepackage[babel,german=guillemets]{csquotes}

% BEGIN ---- Answer to above mentioned questions, here mainly: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165206/biblatex-improving-dynamic-quotation-command
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\varquote}[1]{%
\begingroup
\booltrue{withintextquote}%
% \settowidth doesn't like paragraphs
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
    \def\par{\hspace{3\linewidth}}% If a paragraph is included force long form
    %\let\par\space  % Ignore paragraphs
    \let\footnote\@empty% make sure autocite does not do anything here; this is new
    \let\autocite\@empty
    #1}%
\ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>2\linewidth
    \begin{quote}
        \vspace{-1.4em}
        \singlespacing
        \itshape
        #1
    \end{quote}
\else
    {\blx@blxinit\iffootnote{}{}\itshape #1}%
\fi
\endgroup}
\makeatother
% END ---- Answer to above mentioned questions

\usepackage{lipsum}

 \pagestyle{plain} %Normale Seitenzahlen

\usepackage{gb4e}

\begin{document}

\varquote{\lipsum} 

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example doesn't compile. The bool is not defined, the box is too large (\@tempboxa can't hold a complete lipsum) and now I get an error due to the singlespacing and so I give up. Why didn't you test your code before posting?

Comment: I compiled it using `q` after I copied it from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165206/biblatex-improving-dynamic-quotation-command, changed the name, deleted 2x `\smaller`and added a `\vspace`.

Comment: The example in the linked question contains a `\newbool{withintextquote}` which is missing in your quote. Beside this it is up to you to ensure that an example compiles, so test it and check the log for errors before posting.

Comment: I added the `\newbool{withintextquote}` and it still only compiles using `q` (what I do not mind as long as there is the desired pdf output).

Comment: Well I do mind. If you don't make the effort to remove the errors so that I can run tests, why should I make an effort to find the cause of your problem?

Comment: I would not frame it as question of effort, it is more a question of habituation and (in)competence. I do not have one document that is running without `q` - and I even did not think about it before the discussion occurred here.

Comment: Well you shouldn't ignore errors. That's a very bad habitude. Add `\makeatletter\def\new@fontshape{}\makeatother` before loading gb4e. The package resets \normalfonts as it very old.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added it to my document and it works `q`erfectly. I think my problem is that I lack basic programming skills. However, I will try / make sure to provide smooth mwe in the future. Again, thanks!